# Record USB Webcam to MKV and other formats using DirectShow.Net

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I have a `Graph` in `GraphEdit` which converts a `USB Webcam` into different forms of video like `.MKV`

> Input -> ffdshow Video Converter ->
>   Smart Tee -> AVI Mux -> file.mkv

How can I create the `ffdshow codec` filter in `DirectShow.Net` so I can create this setup in `C#`? I looked and I don't have `ffdshow` listed `FilterCategory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffdshow is listed under

```
FilterCategory.LegacyAmFilter
```

actually a lot of the encoders, decoders and filters are listed in it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a 64 bit version of Windows? If you are, did you make sure you have a 64 bit 
version of ffdshow installed? or that you are building your .net application as X86 explicitly? Additionally, you cannot use an AVI muxer to create an mkv file. You should use a [matroska muxer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/guliverkli/files/Matroska%20Muxer/) instead.

Comment: I downloaded the matroka muxer but i do not know how to put it in graphedit. i dont see anything that explicitly allows me to do so. i have the matroskamuxer.ax from their website. and im running 32bit win 7

Comment: Did you register your *.ax file? Use regsvr32 filename.ax from the command line if you have not registered it yet.

Comment: now i have input -> ffdshow Video Codec -> Smart Tee -> Matroska Muxer -> file writer and that creates a video. that seem correct? would you know how i can replicate this in C# at all? ^^;

Comment: You need to create a graph, enumarate all filters, select those you need, and add them to the graph one by one. Each time you add one filter you should connect its input pin with the output pin of the previous one. You can find (similar) sample code for this on many DirectShow tutorials.

Comment: i found the C++ examples but im in C#. I was using VideoCompressorCategory and wasn't finding it but i switched to LegacyAmFilterCategory and found the matroska muxer for C# use. now i just need to find a file writer because SetOutputFileName is avi asf only

Comment: I'm almost sure that you can still use SetOutputFileName, you should try it again now that you have the right muxer.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know you were using Windows CE. However for Windows 2000+, you can still use this function as long as you pass the muxer GUID as parameter as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd311926%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: this is what ive got when i try. it crashes at line 376 with unknown comexception error  when i use matroska muxer and ffdshow video codec.     http://pastebin.com/BFPU0xZb

Comment: Of couse it crashes... you are still using MediaSubType.Avi. Read again the link I posted. In details

Comment: it happened when i gave it my MKV Guid id too. but i found an example program that does it http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MediaFilesConversionCS.aspx. i made the guid but didnt finish the type CLSID etc.